# How to pass the int of view.py to the {for loop of the django template}?

Tags: python, django

Here is the code of the template I want to pass here in the slice

```
<div class="swiper-container swiper-container2">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  {% for category in smartphone_banners %}
    {% for product in category.product_detail_set.reverse|slice:"1:3:-1" %}
    <div class="swiper-slide py-2">
      <a href="product/{{product.name}}/{{product.id}}" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img src="{{product.imageURL}}" alt="" style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">  
        <h6 class="mt-1">{{product.name}}</h6>
        <p>{{product.price}}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to replace `slice:"1:3:-1" %}` by something like
`slice:"1:totalnu:-1" %}` or `slice:"1:{{totalnu}}:-1" %}`,
but both ways are not working.

How can I pass the value of `totalnu`? Here is my code from `views.py`:

```
        for i in smartphone_banners: 
        for pr in i.product_detail_set.reverse()[1:3:-1]:
            print(pr)
            print(totalnu)
            totalnu = totalnu + 1 
    print(totalnu)
    lists = []
    for ifn in smartphone_banners:
        for prf in ifn.product_detail_set.reverse()[(totalnu - 2):totalnu:-1]:
            print( 'this is the fonal.', prf)
```

Comment: The snippet of `views.py` is difficult to read and quite useless. The correct way for the template is the filter `slice:"1:totalnu:-1"`, but you'll have to memorize `totalnu` in the context for this to work in `view.py`: `context['totalnu'] = totalnu ; render(request, template, context`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the render() method of the Template object with a given set of variables (context).
A Context is similar to a dictionary.
Create context containing variables include totalnu from the `views.py`.

> context = {
> 'totalnu': totalnu
> }

You should have this `render(request, template, context)` in your `views.py`
In your template use `{{ totalnu }}` to pass the value of totalnu